# Angular Material Sidenav issue for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, angular-material2, mat-sidenav

I am using angular version 6 with [material design](https://material.angular.io). I have created one page which uses sidenav component on material design and its stackblitz link is https://angular-pxw1qr.stackblitz.io/sidenav. When i open sidenav page in any Iphone and pull down or pull up the screen sidenav content goes behind the page content and white background is coming at top or bottom of the page.

What i can do to remove this behavior ?

[image: screenshot-1]

[image: screenshot-2]

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `fullscreen` attribute on your sidenav container:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <!-- ... -->
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <!-- ... -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Note that this is just used for styling and does not serve any other purpose.

---

See [the sidenav's stylesheet](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/a620fca9d8af0548b64bb6c3bea0047fb76b701c/src/lib/sidenav/drawer.scss#L40-L46), as well as the [`mat-fill` mixin](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/a620fca9d8af0548b64bb6c3bea0047fb76b701c/src/lib/core/style/_layout-common.scss#L2-L8) for more info.

Comment: adding `fullscreen` didn't work. Issues is coming in iphone device only because of pull down behaviour of ios or safari

Comment: @ranakrunal9 I'm getting the same experience on my laptop. Are you sure that you're only experiencing it on iOS?

Comment: i have checked it in my desktop and then in iphone only not in laptop. In desktop its working fine as there is no pull down thing is going to happen but in iphone user are able to pull down screen